# QT-creator 2.8 wont deploy to android, ant clean debug failed

Tags: android, c++, qt, ant, qt-creator

I just downloaded qt-creator 2.8 and tried deploying my current android project only to get the error: :-1: error: Packaging Error: Command '/usr/bin/ant clean debug' failed.Exit code: 1

I ran ant clean and ant clean debug manually and they worked fine. I also deployed the same project using qt-creator 2.7.1 successfully so I don't think its a java file issue but rather a Qt-creator related one. The same error reproduces regardless of the project, even with a qt hello world. I've tried deleting all of the build and android folders and rebuilding but that didn't work either.

Does anyone know why it wouldn't work?

My system is: 3.8.0-23-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 29 20:22:58 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused from a missing or invalid OpenJDK location setting.  To fix it, go to the Tools -> Options dialog.  Select the Android filter from the left-hand side of the dialog.  Then in the **OpenJDK location** entry field, ensure you have a complete path to an installed OpenJDK.  If you don't have the OpenJDK installed, then Ant will fail.  My path that I set in that field is **/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64**.

Comment: Ended up figuring this out after going through the log a few times. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you were able to figure it out. If the answer would have actually solved the problem, feel free to flag it as the answer for others who come across this question.